# Configure Geany (Ubuntu) to use use HTML syntax highlighting for .tpl files

Tags: ubuntu, geany

I'm trying to configure Geany (Ubuntu) to use use HTML syntax highlighting for `.tpl` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in Tools > Configuration Files